# Does a cable / adaptor for my needs exist? (photos)

Tags: cable, ups

I recently bought a UPS, however, the only outlets take this sort of connector:

[image]

But, the other end of the cables is like this (right):

[image]

The thing is, I really need to connect it to a power bar, so I need a cable that has one end like in the first photo, and the second end like this (right side):

[image]

I've searched around for quite a while, and asked at a few shops, but cannot seem to find a cable that will fulfill this purpose. This seems crazy to me, as I would think that a UPS wouldn't only be able to be attached to devices that take the relatively obscure output seen on the right side of the second image I posted. Do I need to buy another UPS that has the proper connectors?? Please help!!

Comment: If you paste the links to the image we can edit them in for you. However, I'm not sure what you are after - the cable in the second image should go from the back of the UPS to the PSU in the machine/server. I guess something like this but with a (usa?) plug http://shop11.co.uk/images/5055367807071.jpg

Comment: Hi - thanks for editing my post so the images are displayed :) In any case, I'm looking for something with one connector like the first image, and the other connector like the right side of the bottom image. Do you know if something like this exists? Currently the cables that I have (like in image 2), will only connect to a PSU or a monitor, not a power strip.

Comment: basically I guess, I need a cable with two male connectors, but I haven't been able to find anything

Comment: @Evan - the images were inserted by stevenvh on electronics.se. Have you looked at the UPS manufacteros website for accessories?

Comment: What do you need connected to your UPS, and how many outputs does it have?

Comment: The tyope of connector the UPS uses is called an 'IEC'.

Comment: and IEC is more commonly known as a "kettle lead"

Comment: What your asking for is a lead with two male connectors to carry mains? I can't imagine any shop carrying something that lethal.

Comment: Shops here don't carry them but they offered to make one for me, although I obviously won't be going that route now (heh, developing countries)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need a cable with two male connectors

You should not be able to buy a power cord with a male connector at each end.  Such a cord would expose the user to lethal AC voltage once one end is plugged into a live socket.  AC power cords always have a male plug on one end and (if not bare wire for equipment repair) a female receptacle on the other end. That's why you cannot find such a power cord.

Plugging the output of a UPS into a receptacle of a power strip is also an improper electrical connection.  Such a connection would distribute power to the other receptacles, but the on/off switch and circuit breaker will be out of the circuit.

BTW in the electrical trade, a power cord with a male plug on one end and another male plug or alligator clips on the other end is called a [death cord](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1954702).

Perhaps an adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004OC579E) would be suitable for plugging in the power strip's plug into the UPS.

[image: Plug end]
[image: Socket end]

Comment: Thank you for this answer.. I was considering having a male/male cord made, but given that this is known as a "death cord" I'm now obviously not going to be doing that. So, I guess, I just need to buy another UPS..

Comment: As far as what I need it for, I had envisioned using the UPS for my laptop, external monitor, and a router / modem. It seems odd to me that a UPS wouldn't have normal outputs :(

Comment: [This is probably suitable](http://www.audioquest.com/iec-power-adaptors/3-us-power-strip). There are many others available, depending on the socket you need. Just remember the 'female kettle plug' is called a 'female IEC connector' and you should find lots of options.

Comment: @HaydnWVN: thank you very much, that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @sawdust would a power strip such as the one posted work? I mean, I don't even think that there are UPS systems that have, say, 2 prong outputs, how am I supposed to have my modem and router connected to un-interruptible power?

Comment: btw - thanks again, and I feel like this is a very good answer, as it could potentially save someone's life

Comment: [Monoprice.com](http://www.monoprice.com) makes a cable similar to the adapter you've posted. It comes in [1ft length](http://www.monoprice.com/Product/?c_id=102&cp_id=10228&cs_id=1022804&p_id=1302&seq=1&format=1#largeimage) and [6ft length](http://www.monoprice.com/Product/?c_id=102&cp_id=10228&cs_id=1022804&p_id=1303&seq=1&format=1#largeimage)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common (and rather silly) problem with UPSes.
The solution for it is the `C14 plug to universal female adapter`
[image]

It converts those useless C13 sockets into a universal outlet which is compatible with almost all stardars used across Europe and the Americas.

You can buy one for less than US$2 on eBay:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/IEC-320-PDU-UPS-C14-Plug-To-Universal-Female-Socket-Power-Adapter-Converter-New-/161525540556?pt=AU_Electronics_Accessories_Power_Boards_Cables&hash=item259bac26cc